# Google Maps Tile Overlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am currently working on google map and new to it..
I want to know is it possible to divide the map into certain **tiles** with definite height and width and to **color** them.. If yes then somebody can just explain how to do it as i am facing difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are referring to is known as overlays in the Google Maps API. Do you want to achieve something like [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/polygon-simple.html)? (click to show overlay)

The polygons section in the [Google Maps API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Polygons_Overview) would be the place to go to learn more.

Comment: +1 I think this is the best solution if you can achieve the visual affect you are after using GPolygon.  If you need to create more elaborate custom colored tiles, you might need to go with Tile Layer Overlays.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a limited area (geographically) that you would like to color based on map tiles, then you could create a custom tile layer overlay for that area (with each tile colored appropriately).

You can read the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Tile_Layer_Overlays) for Tile Layer Overlays, but the gist is that you create a *GTileLayer* object, then set a property on that object with a function, *getTileUrl*, that is called when Google maps need to insert a tile in Google Maps.

In your *getTileUrl* function, you can return your own version of the tile (which you can draw with a colored tint based on the origional tile):

```
tilelayer.getTileUrl = function(point,  zoom) { 
    if (zoom == 17 && point.x == 38598 && point.y == 49259)
            return "../pics/origional_tile_with_colored_tint.png"; 
};
```

Once you have a a *GTileLayer* object, you instantiate a *GTileLayerOverlay* (passing in your *GTileLayer*) and add it to the GMap2 object (with the *addOverlay* method).

You can find an example of this [here](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo9).